# Weird Ghost CSS Bug

Tags: html, css, reference

How is it possible that my whole website works normally without the css file with all the styles? I have this line in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

I deleted the only styles.css file from the server, but nothing changed. If I delete that line from the header then there are no styles (as expected)

At one point I noticed that none of the css changes I make have any effect, so I made sure that i'm not doing something dumb like editing or referencing the wrong file and that there are not 2 copies of it for some reason. If I change other html files, then I can see the effects, but not the styles file.

I can force it to work by renaming the css file, but I don't really want to do that.

Has anyone seen this happen before?

Comment: Cleared your cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because caching of the CSS. So try clearing the cache of the browser.

You can prevent the CSS caching by below way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1" />
```

Using PHP you can do this trick

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Yup, I think that was it. I cleared "cached images and files" from the browser.